# Access a component and trigger click event from App.vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my template I have one click event

```
<span v-on:click="showGalery()">
```

And I am using one method for it

```
export default {
  name: 'osaka',
  data: function () {
    return {
      galery: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showGalery () {
      this.galery = true
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to trigger this method from App.vue template where is my nav and router links is located?

I am using vue-webpack template. 
I have components, router.js, App.js and main.js structure.

Comment: So this is in a child component and you want to trigger it from the parent? Or handle it in the parent?

Comment: It is better to use property from parent component

Comment: If your "osaka" component is far from your App.vue, you should probably use the flux pattern to trigger `showGalery()` from everywhere.

Comment: @Isak, I using osaka.vue component where I have an html to trigger, App.vue contain navigation with router-link. App.vue is always visible so I guess it's parent. I want to trigger (show/hide) some html in component from navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Remember Vue has a one way data flow, so if you want to set something on the component you can simply pass a prop and use a `watcher` to trigger the change:

```
Vue.component('gallery', {
  template: `<div v-show="gallery">Gallery</div>`,
  props: {
    show: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.gallery = this.show;
  },
  watch: {
    show(val) {
      this.gallery = val;
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      gallery: false
    }
  }
});
```

Then in the parent you would have:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    showGallery: false
  }
});
```

And use the following markup:

```
<gallery :show="showGallery"></gallery>
```

See this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yx1uq370/

Incidentally, if you just want to show hide the entire component, then you can just use v-show on the component itself which

```
Vue.component('gallery', {
  template: `<div>Gallery</div>`
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    showGallery: false
  }
});
```

Then your markup:

```
<gallery v-show="showGallery"></gallery>
```

And here's the fiddle for that: https://jsfiddle.net/gfr9kmub/

One final thing, are you sure that you really need to trigger this from your nav? I would assume that your nav would display the views and the views themselves would take care of this type of state management. Otherwise you may want to look at [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org) to handle this situation

Comment: Thanks for long and detailed answer! I using vue-webpack template, so it's a little bit different.  I'm a beginner with Vue, so I am struggling to make this work.

Comment: What is the issue you are having? If your gallery is being rendered by `vue-router` then you will likely need to rethink how you get the information to the gallery component either by using `vuex` or moving the show/hide functionality to the view itself, which could have the gallery component as a child rather than gallery be the actual view.